# Python suds XML element from nested complex type is not created in SOAP envelope

Tags: python, soap, xsd, wsdl, suds

I'm having issues using [suds-jurko](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/overview) (a fork of [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/)) to handle SOAP services and am running in some issues which seem related to the presence of nested complex types in the wsdl.

Here's the offending service as defined in the wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <definitions name="FormHandler" targetNamespace="http://grid.agnis.net/FormHandler">
  <import namespace="http://security.introduce.cagrid.nci.nih.gov/ServiceSecurity" location="FormHandler?wsdl=ServiceSecurity.wsdl">
    </import>
  <types>
    <schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://grid.agnis.net/FormHandler">
      <import namespace="gme://forms.AGNIS/2.0/net.agnis.forms" schemaLocation="FormHandler?xsd=net.agnis.forms.xsd"/>
        <element name="SubmitFormRevisionRequest">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element name="formRevision">
                <complexType>
                  <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" ref="ns0:FormRevision"/>
```

So there is basically a `<ns0:FormRevision>` element nested inside a `<formRevision>` (which is taken from the current namespace)

I should be getting this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="gme://forms.AGNIS/2.0/net.agnis.forms" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://grid.agnis.net/FormHandler" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:SubmitFormRevisionRequest>
         <ns2:formRevision>
            <ns0:FormRevision>
                <ns0:form publicId="4637831" version="1.0">
                   <ns0:originator uniqueName="cibmtr_center_number:XXX"/>
                </ns0:form>
```

But when I print out the envelope, I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="gme://forms.AGNIS/2.0/net.agnis.forms" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://grid.agnis.net/FormHandler" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:SubmitFormRevisionRequest>
         <ns2:formRevision>
              <form publicId="4637831" version="1.0">
                 <originator uniqueName="cibmtr_center_number:XXX"/>
              </form>
```

Notice the missing `<ns0:FormRevision>` element ? (along with the namespaces `:ns0` for the other elements)

Can anyone assist me in fixing this issue ?

Thanks !!

JP